# IF statements in oracle query (not PL/SQL)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to check for two if conditions in where clause.

Please see the example below.

```
where .... and (
(x = y and flag = 'N') or if(x<>y) flag = 'Y')
```

I want this to be done in one oracle sql statement. I am not allowed to create a procedure.

Edit:
I have reframed the query. `flag 'Y'` is to be checked only if `x not equal to Y`.

Comment: Isn't that just `.. and ((x = y and flag like 'N') or (if x<>y and flag like 'Y'))`?

Comment: yup, removing if ,answers your question and like in ur statement is a equals operation.

Comment: Sorry for wrong question previously. I was not sure about my own requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where .... and ((x = y and flag ='N') or (x<>y and flag ='Y'))`

try this......

Comment: Thank you for the question. I have edited the question. My requirement was something else, which I didn't understand properly, initially.

Comment: @Freakyuser: that is the answer to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
where .... and flag = case when x = y then 'N' else 'Y' end
```